# How to print log in to contentType="image/jpeg jsp files?

Tags: jsp

I'm going to use Img tag to show charts from load jsp file.
I put `<% System.out.println("log") %>` in jsp file which was linked to img tag.
but `<% System.out.println("log") %>` is not working in `contentType="image/jpeg jsp` files.

How should i print log in that type of files?

Comment: out.println() will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out in jsp is a JspWriter object which is created by Jsp automatically, it is used to write something to webpage while System.out.print() is used to output/write something to the console. Use 
`out.println()`

Comment: Also out.println("") is not working too. It does not printed in to eclipse console. Maybe it only can be able in contentType="text/html. not contentType="image/jpeg"...TT..

Comment: well i am saying  `out.println()` instead `System.out.println("log")` , Example  `<%
    out.println("<p>hello</p>");
%>`

Comment: Oh..then there is no any way to print log to console in contentType="image/jpeg ?